# How to get email from generated token

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

Hi I'm trying to get the email user from the given token. I've tried this to parse the token but I always got empty or `{}` value according to this [example](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication) :

```
public function getAuthenticatedUser()
    {
        try {
            if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
                return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
            }

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

        }

        // the token is valid and we have found the user via the sub claim
        return $user;
    }
```

I put the token on the url like this localhost:8000/admin/user/get_all?token={{token}}, I also add the token in the header as `token` NOTE : I'm using **postman** to make the request. But when I try to pass the parse value to the response I always got `{}` value :

```
$result = $this->getAuthenticatedUser();
return response()
            ->json([
              'status'=>'success',
              'user'=>$result,
              'data'=> $users,
            ]);
```

Correct me if I'm wrong here : parse meaning to get the info of the authenticate user such as email? 
Note : I'm using laravel 5.2, and on the route I've builtin middleware jwt-auth and I'm using this [library for generate the token](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth).

Comment: Please add **$** sign in **{{token}}**, like this:`http://localhost:8000/admin/user/get_all?token={{$token}}`. Also, use `return response()->json($user);` instead of `return $user;`

Comment: I'm using postman for adding the {{token}}, and I've tried your suggestion.

Comment: Ohh, I see, I thought you were using it in your blade somewhere... lol... And once you send the request you don't get any response? No response whatsoever? I just tested out your code and it seems to be working fine as it is. Can you tell me if this function is a part of your middleware or any other class? The route you are using, is it using your middleware jwt-auth?

Comment: I didn't get value of the user, I got empty when pass it to json, are you getting the value?

Comment: the middleware is using jwt-auth, and this function is part of my Controller Class, so in my controller I called this function to parse the token and then pass it to json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the response is correct but I don't know why is only got `{}` but actually is not empty, when I tried to get the **column table name** like email :

> `$result->email`

I got the actual email that logged using that token, so now I got it now, thanks everyone.